# Updating the component when data changes (vuejs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a CRUD component and the add user (userRegister) is giving me problems. I am able to successfully add a user, however the view doesn't refresh and the new user doesn't show unless I refresh the page.

Here's the method fired on the Submit button in my Vue Component

```
onSubmit() {
  if (this.password === this.confirmpassword) {
    this.$store
      .dispatch("users/userRegister", {
        operatorNumber: this.operatorNumber,
        operatorName: this.operatorName,
        password: this.password,
        roles: this.operatorRole
      })
      .then(({ status }) => {
        UIkit.offcanvas("#newEmployee").hide();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
      });
  }
  this.resetForm();
},
```

and my store

```
import { axiosInstance } from "boot/axios";

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    operators: []
  },

  getters: {
    operators: state => {
      return state.operators;
    }
  },

  actions: {
    async userRegister({ commit }, payload) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axiosInstance
          .post("user/create", payload)
          .then(({ data, status }) => {
            if (status === 200) {
              resolve(true);

              commit("addUser", payload);
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            reject(error);
            console.log("Error: ", error);
          });
      });
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    addUser: (state, operators) => state.operators.splice(state.operators.length, 0, operators)
  }
};
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: What's the response from server? What are `state.operators`? If you call the mutation directly from an action, with a request resembling the server response, does it do what you want it to?

Comment: Are you sure that `commit('addUser', payload)` shouldn't be `commit('addUser', data)` ? Also can you show the part where you render the operators?

Comment: @roliroli You're right! It was data...well, data.data to be exact because of the way the API is modeled but yes. That worked. Thank you for the guidance my friend

Comment: Glad to read that you found a solution :)